# XAMPP wont load my updated CSS files

Tags: php, html, css, webstorm

I have my site on the localhost by using XAMPP. Every time I edit a file, I change its' extension to `.html` from `.php` to be able to edit it properly with WebStorm.

I noticed for some reason if I modify the `css/scss` while the folder on the server, the updated css will not be loaded. Why is that?

Now I have to edit everything from `.php` to `.html` and move folder out of XAMPP every time I have to edit CSS. And even if I then move again the file into the XAMPP folder, some of my css still wont work..?

Comment: Are you linking your css correctly in your php file after changing the names?

Comment: It might be cached in your browser, you need to clear it and try to run it again.

Comment: Maybe the browser has cached your CSS. Try to reload with Devtools opened (Press F12).

Comment: @DannM No problem :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

3 solutions for this.

1. Use *incognito mode* in your browser.
2. When you refresh to see the css use *control+f5* so you do
           cache-refresh.
3. Remove cache from the *developer console* of your browser.

Pick which fits best for your (personally i use the second one)

Comment: This. Maybe add 'check cloudflare settings in case you use this'. Cloudflare caches as well.

Comment: For a cache refresh on OS-X: Hold down the ⌘ + shift, and then press R

Comment: ctrl + f5 works well, was trying to find a mistake in my ccs for 15 minutes, thanks for saving me time debugging

Answer (score 2):

You can also do a hard reload using **Ctr+Shift+R** and it will start to work again. thats what works for me or try hard refresh using **ctrl+f5**, but hard reload works best for me after I use that I can simple refresh and it works.