# How do I get stylesheets to show on the index.php

Tags: php, html, xampp

I recently changed my index.html file to index.php and now new styles are not taking effect. When I try to alter the already existing styles, nothing happens until I change back to `index.html`. A link to my css file looks like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`

Comment: Please show code example

Comment: `<!-- Main Stylesheet File -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> `

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315772/how-to-import-include-a-css-file-using-php-code-and-not-html-code/6315792

Comment: That didn't help either.

Comment: @ImanPattison Can you show your whole file?

Comment: This looks like probably a setup issue.  Changing the file extension to .php should not change anything.

Comment: My guess would be that you need to use a leading slash - ie: `/css/style.css`

Comment: Are you adding the Stylesheet link inside your `<head></head>`?

Comment: @ImanPattison - How about this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789189/xampp-wont-load-my-updated-css-files/47789345